# Correr dos instancias de tomcat en diferentes puertos

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat

Estoy intentando correr dos instancias en diferentes puertos. Hemos probado server.xml y creando dos connector pero no se crean. 
El puerto esta escuchando pero cuando entro desde el navegador dice que no existe

Comment: Por favor, puedes añadir código o algo para que podamos ayudarte?

Comment: Si no nos añades algo más de información (qué has tocado, qué pruebas has hecho, si se levantan correctamente ambas instancias... no podremos ayudarte

Comment: @CMorillo has podido solucionar el problema con la respuesta planteada?

Answer (score 1):

Es simple, sólo necesitas consultar el fichero de configuración conf/server.xml y añadir un nuevo conector para el puerto que quieras. Por ejemplo, si tienes un conector como este:

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Simplemente copia el mismo código cambiando el puerto. Haz un restart y ya lo tendrás.

Fuente: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231052/running-tomcat-server-on-two-different-ports)